# android - Activity cannot be cast to android.hardware.SensorEventListener

Tags: android

I am trying to make a 2D Racing Game following a tutorial from this website: 
http://www.ajaybadgujar.com/chapter/creating-2d-car-racing-game-in-android-part-1-setting-up-game-startup/

Unfortunately, it is developed for API 8-14 only, and some of its functions are deprecated (namely, the Global.Display.GetHeight/Width). I tried developing it for API 19. I am having difficulties making the GameActivity Class to run (main game screen), when i pulled up the logcat, it throws the "cannon cast to sensoreventlistener" error. Here is the full code for the GameActivity Class which is defective.

`

```
package com.nationalu.gr4.lancerracing2d;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class GameActivity extends Activity {

    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private GameView gameView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        gameView = new com.nationalu.gr4.lancerracing2d.GameView(this);
        setContentView(gameView);

        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensorManager.registerListener((SensorEventListener) this, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        gameView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        gameView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int wd = size.x;
        int ht = size.y;

        int height = Math.round(ht * Global.getProportionateHeight(0.25f));
        int excludedArea = ht - height;
        if (y > excludedArea) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    if (x < wd / 3) {
                        Global.PLAYER_ACTION = Global.BREAKS_PRESSED;
                    } else if (x > (wd / 3) * 2) {
                        Global.PLAYER_ACTION = Global.ACCELERATOR_PRESSED;
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    Global.PLAYER_ACTION = Global.CONTROL_RELEASED;
                    break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
            Global.SENSORE_ACCELEROMETER_X = event.values[0];
        }
    }

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }
}`
```

And, the logcat error:

```
03-27 09:21:21.066 13513-13513/com.nationalu.gr4.lancerracing2d E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.nationalu.gr4.lancerracing2d, PID: 13513
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nationalu.gr4.lancerracing2d/com.nationalu.gr4.lancerracing2d.GameActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.nationalu.gr4.lancerracing2d.GameActivity cannot be cast to android.hardware.SensorEventListener
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2521)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.nationalu.gr4.lancerracing2d.GameActivity cannot be cast to android.hardware.SensorEventListener
    at com.nationalu.gr4.lancerracing2d.GameActivity.onCreate(GameActivity.java:26)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6107)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

Comment: **Activity cannot be cast to android.hardware.SensorEventListener** Error is self explanatory . Use `GameActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener` . And implement the abstract methods of `SensorEventListener`.

Comment: yes, i must have overlooked it in the coding. thank you for the help

Comment: Instead of casting do implement the abstract interface of SensorEventListener.

Answer (score 2):

When you are using `this` in the following code:

```
sensorManager.registerListener((SensorEventListener) this, 
             sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
             SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

You are telling sensorManager to use your class as the parameter. The parameter sensorManager need is an interface named [SensorEventListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEventListener.html). So, you need to make your class has the same behaviour characteristic like SensorEventListener by making your class implementing SensorEventListener.

You can achieve it by using `implements` keyword. Your class should be something like this:

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

  //...
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...
    sensorManager.registerListener((SensorEventListener) this, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
  }

  // This is implemented method from SensorEventListener
  public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    // do something
  }

  // This is implemented method from SensorEventListener
  public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Read more about [SensorManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html).